Have access to NoSql with MoleculerJS
Please I am using a NodeJs Framwork on a project nammed MoleculerJs and i Want to Know if there is possible way to include NoSQL Db Other than mongoose as Cassandra In the FrameWork ?
const SqlAdapter = require("moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize");
module.exports =  new SqlAdapter({
    dialect: "mssql",
    host: "65.108.126.45",
    port: 1433,
    username: "sa",
    password: "2021MyMsSQL",
    database: "GALIO_TEST",
    // Configure the logger options for the moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize service
    logging: false,
})

I am trying to find another const SqlAdapter = require("moleculer-db-adapter-sequelize");  but that is oriented for Nosql database as cassandra and that can be easly use for migration for MSSQL to It

So, you want to be able to use Cassandra? Or you don't want to use Cassandra? Also, you tagged MongoDB, but I'm not seeing why.

I want to use cassandra a nosql as mongoDb in my molecuerJs framework
